# How to adapt Task<T> to provide covariant interface without loss of async/await syntax?

Tags: c#, async-await, syntax, adapter, covariance

There are plenty of classes in .NET standard library that have no interfaces. It ignores the dependency inversion principle. There is the same story with static methods. But we can fluently adapt them like

```
class DateTimeProvider : IDateTimeProvider {
   public DateTime GetNow() => DateTime.Now;
}
```

From time to time, it is necessary to make this adaptation, especially for unit testing. I found one more reason to adapt the class to be interfaced. It is covariance. Missing covariance is painful, and the most painful example is `Task<T>`.The covariance type parameter can't be declared in the generic class. And the following doesn't work.

```
class A {}
class B : A {}
...
Task<A> a = GetBAsync();
```

Hmm, it looks like I need to adapt it to make it has an additional interface. But it isn't so easy as with DateTime. The extra point is that C# has  `async/await` syntax construction that depends on Task. I don't want to lose this construction.

After some investigation, I found out that it is possible to do it by implementing some interfaces. Some of those interfaces are *extensional* (some specific methods/properties that are necessary to be implemented but not included in any C# interface).

So, I have declared the following interfaces (to have covariance) and implemented the following classes.

```
interface IAwaiter<out T> : ICriticalNotifyCompletion
{
    bool IsCompleted { get; }

    T GetResult();
}
```

```
struct Awaiter<T> : IAwaiter<T>
{
    private readonly TaskAwaiter<T> _origin;

    public Awaiter(TaskAwaiter<T> origin) =>
        _origin = origin;

    public bool IsCompleted =>
        _origin.IsCompleted;

    public T GetResult() =>
        _origin.GetResult();

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation) =>
        _origin.OnCompleted(continuation);

    public void UnsafeOnCompleted(Action continuation) =>
        _origin.UnsafeOnCompleted(continuation);
}
```

```
interface IAsyncJob<out T>
{
    IAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter();
}
```

```
struct Job<T> : IAsyncJob<T>
{
    private readonly Task<T> _task;

    public Job(Task<T> task) =>
         _task = task;

    public IAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter() => 
         new Awaiter<T>(_task.GetAwaiter());
}
```

After that `await` started to work with my custom type.

```
class A {}
class B : A {}
...
IAsyncJob<B> bJob = new Job<B>(Task.FromResult(new B()));
IAsyncJob<A> aJob = bJob;
A = await a;
```

Great! But the problem with `async` still exists.
I can't use my interface `IAsyncJob<T>` in the following context:

```
async IAsyncJob<B> GetBAsync() { ... }
```

I investigated it deeper and found out that we can solve the problem by implementing the *extensional* interface and attaching it to my task-like type with attribute. After the following changes, it started to be compilable.

```
public class JobBuilder<T>
{
    public static JobBuilder<T> Create() => null;

    public void Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
        where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine { }

    public void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine) { }

    public void SetResult(T result) { }

    public void SetException(Exception exception) { }

    public IAsyncJob<T> Task => default(IAsyncJob<T>);

    public void AwaitOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(
        ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
            where TAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
            where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine { }

    public void AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(
        ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
            where TAwaiter : ICriticalNotifyCompletion
            where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine { }
}
```

```
[AsyncMethodBuilder(typeof(JobBuilder<>))]
public interface IAsyncJob<out T>
{
    IAsyncJobAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter();
}
```

Obviously, my `JobBuilder<T>` is a stub and I need some implementation that will make my code not only compilable but workable. It should work the same as the default behavior for `Task<T>`.

Maybe, there is some Builder implementation that is used for `Task<T>` by default and I can delegate calls to it (I didn't find this implementation).

How to implement `JobBuilder<T>` to have the same for `IAsyncJob<T>` as .Net provides for `Task<T>`?

---

**Note:**
Of course, I have covariance when I do 'unboxing' of `Task<T>` with 'await'. And the following works fine:

```
A a = await GetBAsync();
IEnumerable<A> aCollection = await GetBCollectionAsync();
```

Also, it isn't a problem to do any conversions including casting at the execution level.

```
static async Task<TOut> Map<TIn, TOut>(
    this Task<TIn> source,
    Func<TIn, TOut> f) => 
        Task.FromResult(f(await source));
...
var someNumber = await Task
    .Run(() => 42)
    .Map(x => (double)x)
    .Map(x => x * 2.2);
```

But it is nothing when I want to have covariance in type system level (inside another interface that uses `Task<T>` in outputs).

The following is still covariant

```
public interface IJobAsyncGetter<out T>
{
    IAsyncJob<T> GetAsync();
}
```

but

```
public interface ITaskAsyncGetter<out T>
{
    Task<T> GetAsync();
}
```

is not.

It excludes covariants from solution design abilities.

And

```
IEnumerable<IJobAsyncGetter<B>> b = ...
IEnumerable<IJobAsyncGetter<A>> a = b;
```

works, but

```
IEnumerable<ITaskAsyncGetter<B>> b = ...
IEnumerable<ITaskAsyncGetter<A>> a = b;
```

doesn't.

It looks like `Task<T>` is one of .NET mistakes that lives with us because of backward compatibility. I see

```
public interface IAsyncEnumerable<out T>
```

is covariant and awaitable interface that works.

I am sure there was possible to provide `ITask<T>` in the same way. But it has not been. So, I am trying to adapt it. It isn't a local code problem for a quick solution. I am implementing a monadic async tree, and it is a core part of my framework. I need **true** covariance. And missing of it blocks me.

Comment: FYI you can do something like `public async Task<object> GetString() => await Task.FromResult("Hello");` where as this doesn't work `public Task<object> GetString() => Task.FromResult("Hello");`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/jam40jeff/ITask/blob/master/Source/MorseCode.ITask/_Root/TaskInterfaceAsyncMethodBuilder%7BTResult%7D.cs) can help?

Comment: "it is necessary to make this adaptation" - **I disagree** and I think you are wasting your time on this. While `Task<T>` is far from perfect, it's such a _fundamental type_ in .NET and C# it should never legitimately need to be abstracted or adapted away. What **real problem** are you trying to solve?

Comment: @GuruStron It looks like exactly what I am looking for. I will investigate and use it. Then I will inform you about the results. Thanks.

Comment: @GuruStron It works. Could you please answer the question (not comment)? And I will have the ability to accept.

Comment: @ValentineZakharenko It would be just link-only answer which is not that recommended.  I can suggest that you put your own answer since you are the one who implemented actual solution.

Comment: @Dai is right; what you're trying to do makes very little sense. The advantage of a class implementing an interface for testing is to facilitate mocking. But you shouldn't be testing `DateTime` or `Task`, so there's no reason to mock them, and therefore no reason for them to implement an interface.

Comment: @Dai In my case, I need to implement a **framework based on monads**, and the missing of **covariance** is such a restriction. I understand your point of *fundamental type* and agree with that in general.  My case is different, and the *fundamental type* point isn't a silver bullet argument. Finally, I implemented it, and .NET/C# provided me the opportunity to do that. Please, recognize it as an investigation. Pragmatism is off-topic of this question.

Comment: @TechInquisitor Mocking isn't a reason to have the interface instead of Task<T> but *covariance*.

Comment: @ValentineZakharenko C#/.NET's type-system is still too inflexible and insufficiently expressive to support ADTs, monads and higher-kinded types (which are necessary to support homomorphisms like endofunctors in the first place). In the past I've tried doing exactly what you're doing right now and kept on hitting these kinds of un-ergonomic difficulties - the utility-types I came-up with in the end were just horribly unusable. I don't meant to discourage you, but personally I'd wait until after CLR's type-system improves. You can probably do this in C++ templates though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [@GuruStron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501279/guru-stron)'s comment, I found [this repo](https://github.com/jam40jeff/ITask) that contains exactly what I was asking about. So, the default builder for `Task<T>` is  `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<T>`.

The adapter of the default builder can be implemented as the following

```cs
public struct JobBuilder<T>
{
    private readonly AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<T> _origin;

    private JobBuilder(AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<T> origin) =>
        _origin = origin;

    public IAsyncJob<T> Task => new Job<T>(_origin.Task);

    public static Builder<T> Create() =>
        new Builder<T>(AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<T>.Create());

    public void Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
        where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine =>
            _origin.Start(ref stateMachine);

    public void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine) =>
        _origin.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);

    public void SetResult(T result) =>
        _origin.SetResult(result);

    public void SetException(Exception exception) =>
        _origin.SetException(exception);

    public void AwaitOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(
        ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
            where TAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
            where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine =>
                _origin.AwaitOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref stateMachine);

    public void AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(
        ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
            where TAwaiter : ICriticalNotifyCompletion
            where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine =>
                _origin.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref stateMachine);
}
```

Comment: Does this just compile/run? Or are you also affected by this bug in the library: https://github.com/jam40jeff/ITask/issues/14 or have you found another solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going through all this, I would recommend writing simple wrapper function for that specific problem:

```
// Sample classes
class Parent { }
class Child : Parent { }

public class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<Parent> taskToGetChild = As<Child, Parent>(GetChildAsync);
        // some code
        var b = await taskToGetChild;
    }

    static async Task<Child> GetChildAsync()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(new Child());
    }

    // Here's the method that allow you to mimic covariance.
    static async Task<TOut> As<TIn, TOut>(Func<Task<TIn>> func)
        where TIn : TOut
    {
        return (TOut)await func();
    }
}
```

Comment: `await Task.FromResult` is redundant. IMHO you should just have `static async Task<TOut> As<TIn, TOut>(Task<TIn> t) where TIn : TOut => (TOut)await t;`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Good suggestion, thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

Frankly I don't know how to implement what you are looking for. However, there is a easy workaround with minimal syntax. The idea is you await `GetBAsync` convert `B` to `A`, wrap `A` in a task and then return it. It is a extra-step, but a simple one:

```
Task<A> a = Task.Run(async () => (A)await b.GetBAsync());
```

That way you fully keep the `async/await` functionality.

Answer (score -3):

You can still adapt `Task<T>` to a degree without having to implement a custom task-like type. `IAsyncEnumerator<T>` can give you a bit hint.

I'd define an interface like this:

```
interface IAsync<out T>
{
    T Result { get; }
    
    Task WaitAsync();
}
```

Implement the interface with a wrapper of `Task<T>`:

```
public class TaskWrapper<T> : IAsync<T>
{
    private readonly Task<T> _task;

    public TaskWrapper(Task<T> task)
    {
        _task = task;
    }

    public T Result => _task.Result;

    public async Task WaitAsync()
    {
        await _task;
    }
}
```

Add an extension method to complete the async action and return a `Task` of result:

```
public static class AsyncExtensions
{
    public static async Task<T> GetResultAsync<T>(this IAsync<T> task)
    {
        await task.WaitAsync();
        return task.Result;
    }
}
```

With the above, you could do in your code:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }

IAsync<B> b = new TaskWrapper<B>(Task.FromResult<B>(new B()));
IAsync<A> a = b;

IEnumerable<IAsync<B>> bList = new List<IAsync<B>>();
IEnumerable<IAsync<A>> aList = bList;

A aValue = await a.GetResultAsync();
```